# Any way (Best way) to alter user's IP address before passing query onto remote server

Tags: php, curl, proxy, header, ip

We have a script running on a managed server (LAMP) that uses php/curl to post a user's query to a remote server and then display the results that are returned. What we would like to do is anonymize the users by passing our server IP to the remote server instead of the user IP. How can we implement this? Any suggestions will be appreciated and tried with no hard feelings or snide comments if it doesn't work. We're out of ideas. Thank you.

Comment: You are already using your own IP since you're making the connection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tor

```
curl bot.whatismyipaddress.com => 91.240.86.250
```

use sock:

```
curl bot.whatismyipaddress.com --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 => 178.17.174.99
```

use php

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 127.0.0.1 . ":" . 9050);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
```

Comment: Thank you redroid, this is exactly what we needed. (we used your php/curl_setopt() suggestion)  Works perfectly. Cheers!